# How to write Urdu language in LaTEX?

Tags: latex

I am writing a research paper in LaTeX. The paper is about Urdu Language Processing and i have to write Urdu words within English paragraphs. I have tried this:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontface{\urdu}[Script=Arabic]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq}

#in the text, write Urdu like this:

In your document {\urdu اردو ایسے لکھیں} write Urdu like this.
```

But it doesnot work for me. I need help for this.

Comment: `But it doesnot work for me` means what?

Comment: If i write any word in Urdu it appears in opposite direction. Like if i want to write اردو i have to write it like ودرا. Than it will appear like اردو in the pdf output.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should rather be asked on tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: seems you got issue with LTR. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54320/ltr-sequences-within-rtl-text-alternative-to-cumbersome-markup ?

Comment: Maybe this package https://ctan.org/pkg/arabxetex can help?

Answer (score 10):

While writing in multiple languages under `polyglossia` you have to specify them ([see this for a detailed answer on how to write Urdu - English mixed documents in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493274/how-to-write-an-english-urdu-mixed-document-in-latex)).
Here is a MWE.

```
documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{urdu}
\setmainfont[Path=/Users/ghalib/Library/Fonts/]{ufonts.com_jameel-noori-nastaleeq.ttf}

\begin{document}

In your document \texturdu{ اردو ایسے لکھیں} write Urdu like this.

\vspace{0.5in}

\noindent
\begin{center}
\texturdu{
اردو ہے جس کا نام ، ہمیں جانتے ہیں داغ \\
سارے جہاں میں دھوم ہماری زباں کی ہے\\
\hspace{6cm} (داغ دھلوی)
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]